# Is there a fast way to debug mobile vibrations in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, haptic-feedback

I'm trying to rapidly preview and iterate on different Android vibrations that I'm making through Unity3D. Currently, the only way that I know how to successfully do this is to build the project each time. This is really tedious and takes a very long time. Are there any ways to rapidly test different vibrations?

I've tried using UnityRemote, which works great for quickly debugging just about everything Android related *except* vibrations. Vibrations don't really work in Unity Remote since it's mirroring the Unity player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way around the build process with Unity, other than the Unity Remote app. I would try to place as many Android vibrations in a single build as you can, and make an interface to test them all.